# Using Accord.Imaging in UWP

Tags: imaging, accord.net

(apologies for beginner question) I am trying to use Accord.Net Imaging function in an UWP windows 10 App. Any function I try  gives me an error:

The type 'Bitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.The type 'Bitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

although I included Using System.Drawing (which includes Bitmap)

UnmanagedImage unmanagedImage = UnmanagedImage.FromByteArray(bytes);

Answer (score 2):

If you're using NuGet, you can install the following package to get `System.Drawing`, and thus access to the `Bitmap` class: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2/5.2.0-preview1-r131

Note that this is a prerelease version, so you'll need to check the box that says "Include prerelease" next to the search bar if using the Visual Studio NuGet GUI.

Comment: NuGet `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` is deprecated now, but I am still getting this warning. What should I do to resolve it?